# How to animate (moving by default) and inanimate (make stationary on tap) colliding objects

Tags: iphone, android, lua, coronasdk

Hey tired this new code to animate objects (here bubbles) and make them stationary using sprites. The code is as below,

```
local ui = require("ui")

local gameUI = require("gameUI")
local easingx  = require("easingx")
require "sprite"

display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()
physics.setScale( 60 )

local backgroundPortrait = display.newImage( "sky.png", 0, 0 )
local backgroundLandscape = display.newImage( "sky.png", 80, 80 )
backgroundLandscape.isVisible = false
local disp = backgroundLandscape

local function selectBubble( event )
    local tapped = event.target  --event.target is how Corona points to the tapped bubble
    if ( tapped.bubbleSelected == false ) then
        local vx,vy = tapped:getLinearVelocity()
        tapped.xVel = vx  --stores the current velocity into bubble's "xVel" variable
        tapped.yVel = vy  --likewise for yVel
        tapped:setLinearVelocity( 0,0 ) --set bubble's velocity to 0!
        tapped.currentFrame = (3)
        tapped.bubbleSelected = true
    elseif ( tapped.bubbleSelected == true ) then
        tapped:setLinearVelocity( tapped.xVel, tapped.yVel )  --read previous velocity and set
        tapped.bubbleSelected = false
    end
end

--BUBBLE1
local bubble1 = sprite.newSprite( spriteSet1 )
bubble1.x = 100
bubble1.y = 100
physics.addBody(bubble1, {bounce=0.04,  filter = bubbleCollisionFilter})
bubble1:setLinearVelocity( 2, 4 )
bubble1:addEventListener( "tap", selectBubble )
bubble1.bubbleSelected = false
bubble1:prepare("bubble")
bubble1:play()

--BUBBLE2
local bubble2 = sprite.newSprite( spriteSet1 )
bubble2.x = 210
bubble2.y = 20
physics.addBody(bubble2, {bounce=0.05,  filter = bubbleCollisionFilter})
bubble2:setLinearVelocity( 2, 4 )
bubble2:prepare("bubble")
bubble2:play()

--BUBBLE3
local bubble3 = sprite.newSprite( spriteSet1 )
bubble3.x = 100
bubble3.y = 17
physics.addBody(bubble3, {bounce=0.02,  filter = bubbleCollisionFilter})
bubble1:setLinearVelocity( 1, 2 )
bubble3:prepare("bubble")
bubble3:play()

--BUBBLE4
local bubble4 = sprite.newSprite( spriteSet1 )
bubble4.x = 310
bubble4.y = 20
physics.addBody(bubble4, {bounce=0.4,  filter = bubbleCollisionFilter})
bubble4:setLinearVelocity( 2, 4 )
bubble4:prepare("bubble")
bubble4:play()
```

The problem is firstly the code doesn't seem to work. Secondly though the bubble changes color on tap (this color is same for most). Yet, each bubble has a unique letter on it. How to get this to work. Please help.

Comment: Be more specific about what isn't working. Like, is there an error message when you run that code? What line is the error on?

Comment: I just noticed in your profile you had already asked about this in a previous question. Instead of simply posting it again you should work on improving your question by explaining things better. What do you mean by "animate"? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what exactly you're asking because your question is pretty vague (what does "animate" mean? And what do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? explain these terms because they can mean multiple things) but I think you want to set the physics bodies to "static" in the tap event listener. Refer here for what I'm talking about:

http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/bodybodytype

So inside the selectBubble() function you would type something like tapped.bodyType="static"